# Reviewing an AC dimmer - trying to understand

Tags: adc, ac, 5v

I'm apology if the title is kinda generic but I found a (on a AC) which use IC and a triac and there is some points I don't really get.

Image from [this application note](http://www.freescale.com/files/microcontrollers/doc/app_note/AN2839.pdf?fsrch=1):

[image]

[Datasheet](http://www.freescale.com/files/microcontrollers/doc/data_sheet/MC68HC908QY4.pdf?pspll=1) used as reference.

1. About the PTA0 pin :

   1. How can the pin accept 120v since the range of the ADC is VSS to VDD (Page 161).
      The maximum absolute voltage for input is VSS-0.3 to VDD+0.3 which is far away from 120v, (Page 149)
   2. What about -120v? The PTA0 shouldn't have a diode to be a voltage above 0v?
   3. Why using resistors for the zero-crossing on the PTA0 pin? If it is to limit the current I tought input pin handled them.
2. Z1 shouldn't do a shortcut when it reach the breakdown voltage from C1 to Ground? (C1 -> D2 -> Z1) (I assume the top graph is the positive side)

   2. I'm trying to know why it need 0.5W, I don't think it may be the IC (25mA maximum for PTA* pins, but I don't find the power consuption overall (50mA could be the overall consuptions (including PTA* output pin I hope) ?)

Also, there is an exemple using a generic opto coupler where they connect the anode to a 100k which then go to the AC :

1. I know LED work with current instead of voltage... but i'm kinda surprise they work at 120v. Is it really possible or this is only true for opto coupler?
2. Should -120v destroy the led since it is much more higher than the regular 5v reverse input voltage?

Thanks

Comment: Kind of distracted right now, but I think that circuit is actually floating on the AC line.   So it's not like you just hooked up 120V to a micro connected to 0-5V.  The whole floating power supply thing is kind of cool, but only usable when no one can come in contact with the circuit.  It's just as dangerous as a live main.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I)

1. It doesn't. Whether it's low or high, the resistors act as a pull-up while also providing the needed signal. The current, for a supposed logic low would be \$115\sqrt{2}/940k\Omega = 173 \mu A\$
2. As Some Hardware Guy said, it's floating so the reference is 0V because its supply is mono-alternance and done through a capacitive impedance (reactance) of \$1\mu F\ = 2.65k\Omega \$ (60Hz) or\$  3.18k\Omega\$ (50Hz).
3. They're there for not actually putting the pin to 160V, your fear at #1.

II)

1. C1 has the mentioned reactance, acting as an "active" resistor, limiting current through Z1.

   1. I couldn't find the 0.5W you're talking about.

The rest:

1. The LED will still have ~2V foreard voltage drop and the maximum current will  be: \$ I_{max}=\frac{115\sqrt{2}-2}{100k\Omega} = 1.62mA\$
2. There won't be -120V since its reference will be the IC's supply, therefore the bridge will clamp the voltage.

You're welcome, but you should really try those [simple circuits](http://www.circuitstoday.com/diac-applications) that have proven to be good enough, instead of choosing this.